# How to make my if (condition) work only when it's > 768 px?

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, window

My script works, however it works only half way, since I'm giving if (condition) and it's working only after refresh the cache on the browser.

My main goal is to make my subheader fixed on desktop version and it should be not fixed on mobile devices

This is my code

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
if(windowWidth > 768){
    var fixedMenu = $('.subheader-wrapper.row');
    var navOffset = fixedMenu.offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(scrollPos > navOffset) {
            fixedMenu.addClass('fixed');
            fixedMenu.addClass('animated fadeIn');
        }
        else {
            fixedMenu.removeClass('fixed');
            fixedMenu.removeClass('animated fadeIn')
        }
        if ( window.location.pathname == '/' ||  window.location.pathname == '/o-kompanii' || window.location.pathname == '/otzyivyi' || window.location.pathname == '/vopros-otvet' ) {
            var infoUs = $('#info-us');
            var infoUsOff = infoUs.offset().top;
            if (scrollPos > infoUsOff - 480) {
                infoUs.find('div:first-child').addClass('animated fadeInLeft');
                infoUs.find('div:nth-child(2)').addClass('animated fadeInUp');
                infoUs.find('div:last-child').addClass('animated fadeInRight');
            }
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: So if you want to have different styles for mobile devices why not `CSS3` `@media Rule`?

Comment: Here is a simple [**JsFiddle Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/26n5m8jt/) for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest this to use with the help of css for exact output. `$(window).width();` might be different in different browsers. Therefore we can get the desired result using the help of css and media query.

```
.test {
        display: none;
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        .test {
            display: block;
        }
    }
```

JQuery

```
$(window).on( "resize" , function () {
        if (jQuery(".test").is(":hidden")) {
            // CODE HERE
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

> it's working only after refresh the cache on the browser.

You are assigning the event handler only when `windowWidth > 768` and your code doesn't seem to be responsive to changing `windowWidth` as well.

Use [resize](https://api.jquery.com/resize/) event and put conditions inside the event handlers

```
$(window).on( "resize" , function () {
  if ( $(window).width() > 768 )
  {
     //add scroll event now
  }      
});
```